# TypeError: inputProps.onChange.call is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My test is failing because of the title error. This is my setup and test:

```
  let renderedOutput;
    beforeEach(() => {
      const handleBodyChange = sinon.stub();
      renderedOutput = mount (<MessageDetail handleNameChange handleBodyChange/>);
    });

  it('calls the handleBodyChange function', () => {
    const input = renderedOutput.find('#senderMsgBody');
    input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'My message' } });
    expect(handleBodyChange).to.have.been.calledWith();
  });
```

This is my `MessageDetail` component:

`Name: <input id="senderMsgName" value={this.props.nameValue} onChange={this.props.handleNameChange}/>`

and this is the prop I pass down:

```
<MessageDetail
          handleBodyChange={this.handleBodyChange.bind(this)}
          bodyValue={this.state.bodyValue}
        />
```

can post more code but any idea why I am getting this error as seems like it should work

Comment: Can you put here the code for class that extends ` React.Component`?

Comment: I have, the `MessageDetail` component extends React.component @ShridharR.Kulkarni

Comment: Sometimes you get this error if you miss bindings in the constructor. I think you should post more code so that community can help you if you are missing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

`<MessageDetail handleNameChange handleBodyChange/>` (in your `beforeEach` function) doesn't bind the properties to the component you are rendering. 
You defined the props, but did not pass any value.

It should probably be something like

```
<MessageDetail 
    {handleNameChange} 
    {handleBodyChange}/>
```

or

```
<MessageDetail 
    handleNameChange={handleNameChange}
    handleBodyChange={handleBodyChange}/>
```

Comment: if I try that it just says: `handleNameChange is not defined`

Comment: Yeah, you only created a stub for your `handleBodyChange`. You'll probably need one for your `handleNameChange` as well.